# Is the empty set an element in every base of a given topology?

Tags: general-topology

A common example of a base for the usual topology of ${\rm I\!R}$ is the set of open intervals. If you intersect two disjoint open intervals though you get the empty set. Now this set is clearly open since it's in the definition of a topology. My question is, why do most definitions assert that the base of a topology has this closure property but give examples like this where it disregards empty intersections. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, not every base needs to contain the empty set. In fact, most (that we care about) don't. Remember that the base condition is that for any $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there exists base element $B_3$ such that $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$. This condition doesn't necessitate the inclusion of the empty set in the base.

Comment: This makes sense. The empty set has no elements so we don’t have to worry about x being in another B

Comment: Basic Topology by Armstrong uses the definition where any finite intersection of base sets is a base set. So with this definition it’s less clear but with the definition everyone gave me here it is clear.

Comment: Where exactly in "Basic Topology" does Armstrong state the definition of a base in the form that you give?

Comment: Theorem 2.5 on page 31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a base of a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ is a set $B\subset\mathcal P(X)$ such that every element of $\tau$ can be written as an union of elements of $B$. It is *not* required that the intersection of any two elements of $B$ is again an element of $B$. So, that fact that, in $\Bbb R$, we sometimes have $(a,b)\cap(c,d)=\emptyset$ is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing some things here. The base definition here is: A base is a system of open sets so that any open set is a union of some of these sets.

Now, what you appear to be confused about is the property: If you have a system $B$ of sets in $X$ that has two properties:

1. $\bigcup_{M\in B} M = X$
2. For $M_1,M_2$ the intersection is a union of sets in $B$

then $B$ is a basis for one unique topology on $X$.

So what if $M_1,M_2$ are disjoint? Note that an empty union is by definition the empty set. So we can always write the empty set as an empty union.

EDIT: Some additional information. Why do we need this? In a topology a finite intersection of open sets has to be open. So if $B$ is a basis then such an intersection has to be a union of this kind. By distributivity if this holds for two sets, it also holds for finitely many sets.

Now we want to prove:
$$ \tau:=\{\bigcup_{M\in A}M : A\subset B\}$$
is a topology. Clearly $\emptyset =\bigcup_{M\in\emptyset}M$ and by assumption $\bigcup_{M\in B}M = X$.
Trivially if $C\subset \mathcal P(B)$ then
$$ \bigcup_{A\in C} \bigcup_{M\in A}M = \bigcup_{M\in\bigcup_{A\in C}A}M$$

So it remains: If $A_1,A_2\subset B$ then
$$  \left(\bigcup_{M\in A_1}M\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{M\in A_2}M\right)= \bigcup_{M_1\in A_1} M_1\cap\left(\bigcup_{M\in A_2}M\right) = \bigcup_{M_1\in A_1}\bigcup_{M_2\in A_2}M_1\cap M_2$$

Since $M_1\cap M_2$ is a union of sets in $B$ the whole thing is a union of sets in $B$. By recursion the property also holds for finite intersections.